# can interface extend other class ?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, interface

I found this on zend website

```
interface ResultSetInterface extends \Traversable, \Countable
{
    public function initialize($dataSource);
    public function getFieldCount();
}
```

is it possible that interface Extend Class ? and multiple Inheritance? as i know   PHP  doesn't support multiple Inheritance. [Click Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

can anyone clear this.

Comment: Interface can extend one other interface, but not other classes.  And for multiple inheritance, see [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

> Interfaces can be extended like classes using the extends operator.

They can extend only other interfaces.

Comment: Which just make sense to me. I mean how would like to extends anything else? Great!